# install scipy with Active Python on mac os

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scipy

as per the instructions i did
pypm install scipy

command line in comes back with

The following packages will be installed into "~/Library/Python/3.2" (3.2):
 scipy-0.9.0
Hit: [pypm-free.activestate.com] scipy 0.9.0
Installing scipy-0.9.0
error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 4

any help appreciated.

Comment: Which exact file of scipy are you installing (also a pointer to the instructions you are using)

Comment: why not just do `pip install --user scipy`